# Function of putting number format to string,is it possible or will i have to make it to an int or double or float format?

Tags: java

**My 1st function**

//working

```
public static String formatSalary(Double salary){
  NumberFormat numFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
  DecimalFormat deciFormat = (DecimalFormat) numFormat;
  deciFormat.applyPattern("#0.00");
  deciFormat.setGroupingUsed(true);
  deciFormat.setGroupingSize(3);
  return deciFormat.format(salary);
}
```

**My planned 2nd function**

```
public static String formatCommission(String commission){
  NumberFormat numFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
  DecimalFormat deciFormat = (DecimalFormat) numFormat;
  deciFormat.applyPattern("#0.00");
  deciFormat.setGroupingUsed(true);
  deciFormat.setGroupingSize(3);
  return deciFormat.format(commission);
}
```

*Is this possible or will I have to make it to number format, the parameters being thrown come from database I used String cause there are some rows having null in commission column need your opinion about this*

Comment: Not sure what you need. But it seems like you need to convert a `String` representing a number in Locale A format into another `String` representing the *same number* in Locale B format. Is that what you need?

Comment: no,,its not that,its just util class designated for their respective columns,,its ok now,,already done it

Comment: public static String CommissionChecker(String commission){
    if (commission == null || commission.isEmpty()){
      commission = "0.00";
    }
    Double comm = Double.parseDouble(commission);
    NumberFormat numFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
    DecimalFormat deciFormat = (DecimalFormat) numFormat;
    deciFormat.applyPattern("#0.00");
    deciFormat.setGroupingUsed(true);
    deciFormat.setGroupingSize(3);
    return deciFormat.format(comm);
  }